# Symfony and FullCalendar, how to send data from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar.io with tattali/calendar-bundle.

I want to display a calendar for a lending objects service.
So the calendar must show the days during which one object is unavialable.

The problem is I can't manage to send the object to fullcalendar so I can get the reservations and the days the object is reserved.

Here is my code for the Javascript :

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
          
            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
              plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
              headerToolbar: {
                left: "prev,next",
                center: "title",
                right: "dayGridMonth,listWeek",
              },
              buttonText: {
                today: "Today",
                month: "month",
                week: "week",
                day: "day",
                list: "list",
              },
          
              displayEventTime: false,
              initialDate: Date.now(),
              locale: "fr",
              firstDay: "1",
              // editable: true,
              // dayMaxEvents: true,
              eventSources: [
                {
                  url: "/fc-load-events",
                  method: "POST",
                  extraParams: {
                    filters: JSON.stringify({}),
                  },
                  failure: () => {
                    console.log("There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!");
                  },
                  },
                  {
                    url: "/json-feed",
                    method: "POST",
                    extraParams: {
                      filters: JSON.stringify({}),
                    },
                    failure: () => {
                      console.log("There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!");
                    },
                  }
              ],
                events: [
               
                {
                  groupId: "association ouverte", // recurrent events in this group move together
                  daysOfWeek: ["3", "6"],
                  display: "background",
                  color: "#5c995e",
                },
              ],
          
              timeZone: "UTC",
            });
            calendar.render();
          });
```

The Symfony controller :

```
// controller for displaying the page :

    #[Route('/object-details/{slug}', name: 'object-details', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function detailsObject(
        Object $object,
        LoanRepository $loan,
    ): Response {
       
        return $this->render('home/details-object.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
            'object' => $object,
            'loan' => $loan,
        ]);
    }

// controller for getting json :

    #[Route('/json-feed', name: 'json-feed')]
    public function getJson(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse(['objet' => 12]);
        dump($response);
        return $response;
    }
```

The json-feed route works but I don't know how to send the object details with it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to do it that was pretty easy !
I was trying to send the object's data as a json but I just needed to get it with some jquery on the dom.

I did this :

```
//...
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
// I get the object id from the dom :
  var object = $("#objet-calendar").find('p').text();
//...
```

then I added it to the filters :

```
//...
{
                  url: "/fc-load-events",
                  method: "POST",
                  extraParams: {
                    filters: JSON.stringify({'object' : object}),
                  },
                  failure: () => {
                    console.log("There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!");
                  },
                  },
//...
```

Finally in onCalendarSetData()

```
//...
  public function onCalendarSetData(CalendarEvent $calendar, $router)
    {
        $start = $calendar->getStart();
        $end = $calendar->getEnd();
        $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

        $object = $this->objectRepo->findOneById($filters);
        $object_id = $objet->getId();
//...
```

And it works